# Wordpress Home Page Password Protected For User

Tags: php, wordpress

I am hoping someone can help me in this problem.
Who can I Password Protect my wordpress site pages for user , Whenever a user visit to my site Home page .They seen Password input Field just. not seen Whole page content . Including Header Footer

Answer (score 0):

You can password protect your complete site using `.htaccess` and `.htpasswd` file

Follow the steps below to password protect your site

1) Create a `.htaccess` file with the following in application root folder:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Password Protected Area"
AuthUserFile /var/www/html/wordpress/.htpasswd
Require valid-user
```

2) Create a `.htpasswd` file in the same folder `/var/www/html/wordpress`

The `.htpasswd` file should contain your password Use the link [here](http://www.htaccesstools.com/htpasswd-generator/) to generate the password